# Problem with reading data from Cache API (still in promise?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

That is my first post here. I am not well skilled in asynchronous code so can not resolve the problem by myself

In a React/Redux app I have added cache. The idea behind it is to have something like 'Favorites' functionality but on clients' computer. So, I would like to store over there some data about books. While writing to cache works I can not successively dispatch data to store> Now my code looks like this:

```
export function fetchFromFavorites() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const URL = getState().books.currentURL;
    const Cache = await caches.open(URL);
    Cache.matchAll()
      .then(function (response) {
        const ar = [];
        response.forEach(async item => ar.push(await item.json()));
        return ar;
      })
      .then(response => dispatch(test(response)));
  };
}
```

In the code above test is an action that only sets the state field with payload. While the payload can be log-consoled from reducer, I can not perform on that any further action with another external function, well-checked on that kind of data. Besides DevTools mark it with blue 'i' what indicates that it has been calculated very lately. What is wrong with that code? BTW - it has nothing to do with service workers it is just inside regular React.

Comment: “ I can not perform on that any further action with another external function, well-checked on that kind of data.” Can you elaborate more on what this means, it is t clear what your problem is or what you’re trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are passing to `response.forEach` is returning a promise. You'd need to wait for all of those promises to resolve before returning `ar`.

For example, you may use something like:

```js
// await all promises to be fulfilled before proceeding.
// note that we use response.map instead of forEach as
// we want to retain a reference to the promise returned
// by the callback.
// Additionally, we can just return the promise returned
// by `item.json()`
await Promise.all(response.map(item => item.json());
```

Remember, any function marked as `async` will return a promise wrapping the function's return type.

Note that you're mixing async/await with older style then/catch promises here. For consistency and ease of reading, you may want to use one style consistently.